# mysql selecting and making an average

Tags: mysql, select, filtering

I have a DB that stores temps, sensor number and times entered. Understand that I am very new to this, but would really appreciate some help please !

DB fields :

```
temp,tempdate,tempttime,sensorno, timeentered
```

What I'm trying to do is write a query to run in php that will select the data for the current day, look at the times and average the temp per hour. So it would take all data belonging to the same hour i.e from 00:00:00 to 00:01:00 (Per sensor) add it up and then divide it by the amount of values stored to give an average for that hour.

Example data :

```
temp tempdate   tempttime sensorno  timeentered
5   2014-12-21  00:00:00    1   2014-12-21 00:00:00
8.5 2014-12-21  00:00:01    2   2014-12-21 00:00:01
9   2014-12-21  00:00:02    3   2014-12-21 00:00:02
4.5 2014-12-21  00:00:02    4   2014-12-21 00:00:02
9   2014-12-21  00:00:03    5   2014-12-21 00:00:03
5.5 2014-12-21  00:00:03    6   2014-12-21 00:00:03
5   2014-12-21  00:01:08    1   2014-12-21 00:01:08
8.5 2014-12-21  00:01:09    2   2014-12-21 00:01:09
9   2014-12-21  00:01:09    3   2014-12-21 00:01:09
5   2014-12-21  00:01:10    4   2014-12-21 00:01:10
9   2014-12-21  00:01:10    5   2014-12-21 00:01:10
5.5 2014-12-21  00:01:11    6   2014-12-21 00:01:11
5   2014-12-21  00:02:16    1   2014-12-21 00:02:16
8.5 2014-12-21  00:02:16    2   2014-12-21 00:02:16
9   2014-12-21  00:02:17    3   2014-12-21 00:02:17
5   2014-12-21  00:02:18    4   2014-12-21 00:02:18
9   2014-12-21  00:02:18    5   2014-12-21 00:02:18
5.5 2014-12-21  00:02:19    6   2014-12-21 00:02:19
5   2014-12-21  00:03:24    1   2014-12-21 00:03:24
8.5 2014-12-21  00:03:24    2   2014-12-21 00:03:24
8.5 2014-12-21  00:03:25    3   2014-12-21 00:03:25
4.5 2014-12-21  00:03:25    4   2014-12-21 00:03:25
9   2014-12-21  00:03:26    5   2014-12-21 00:03:26
5.5 2014-12-21  00:03:26    6   2014-12-21 00:03:26
```

So my current query is

```
use ponddb;
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    pondtemp
WHERE
    timeentered >= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the query that you want:

```
SELECT tempdate, hour(temptime) as temphour, sensorno, avg(temp) as avgtemp
FROM pondtemp
WHERE tempdate = CURDATE()
GROUP BY tempdate, hour(temptime), sensorno
ORDER BY tempdate, hour(temptime), sensorno;
```

I included the date as well as the time in case you want to extend the `where` clause to handle multiple dates.

Comment: Perfect, I have one last question -since im am new at this Im using phplot to show the graph, but im not sure im using the right names with your code - Although it works perfectly in mysqlworkbench : if ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
    $sensorno = $row->sensorno;
    $timeentered = $row->hour;
    $temp = $row-> temp;

    switch ($sensorno)

Comment: @JezWalton . . . I added column aliases for reasonable names in the result set.

Comment: Gordon Thanks so much - not quite sure how to use column aliases in the code for the graph - will try googling it ?

Comment: The result set has four columns, `tempdate`, `temphour`, `sensorno`, and `avgtemp`.  You would access them as you would access any columns in a result set.

Comment: even like this {
    $sensorno = $row->sensorno;
    $timeentered = $row->temphour;
    $temp = $row-> avgtemp;Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$hour in C:\xampp\htdocs\jez\AVEPondTempGraphtodayonly.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$avgtemp in C:\xampp\htdocs\jez\AVEPondTempGraphtodayonly.php on line 57

Comment: The `as` keyword should definitely be renaming the variables and php should recognize them.

Comment: Gordon, im now getting to grips with this - thank you - If I only wanted to return 6 values - IE total ave for each sensor for today, whats the best way to do that ?

Comment: @JezWalton . . . Remove the `hour(temptime)` from the `select`, `group by`, and `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

if your hour field is in date time type, the following should work

```
select avg(temp) temp_avg, hour(tempttime) time_hour from my_table
where tempdate=curdate()
group by time_hour
```

if its type is string then instead of hour(tempttime) use left(hour,2).